# list in an object nested in an array react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to map the Difficulty list to a react component. How do I do it? I need to map it as a list to a component

```
{
"Difficulty": [
    "Easy",
    "Medium",
    "Hard",
    "Very Hard"
],
"Style": [
    "Exhibition",
    "Season",
    "Franchise",
    "Tournament"
],
"Sport": "Basketball",
"QuarterLengths": [
    6,
    12
]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `data.Difficulty.map`? What have you tried? Is there an issue? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

```
    const data = {
"Difficulty": [
    "Easy",
    "Medium",
    "Hard",
    "Very Hard"
],
"Style": [
    "Exhibition",
    "Season",
    "Franchise",
    "Tournament"
],
"Sport": "Basketball",
"QuarterLengths": [
    6,
    12
]
}

const SomeComponent = () => {
       return <div>{data.Difficulty.map((d)=><span>{d}</span>)}</div>
}
```